# How to stop custom functions from executing periodically in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have several custom functions in their own column. Each function takes a few values from the same row and do their calculations and output the result into several columns horizontally. This worked fine, but the problem is when I check the execution log in the app script back end, I'm seeing that those functions were running by themselves periodically even though I have not changed anything from the sheet. I have a thousand rows of data and those custom functions will take several minutes each time. The last time I checked the functions just ran by themselve about 70 minutes apart.

I called my function like this is the cell:
`=calThem(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(E2))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(F2))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(G2))))`

An example of my functions:

```
function rgb2hsl(r, g, b) {
    var
        min = Math.min(r, g, b),
        max = Math.max(r, g, b),
        delta = max - min,        
        h, s, l = max;

    // some calculations
    
    return [[h, s, l]];
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: In Excel, the function Indirect would cause this to happen as it's a volatile function. Google Sheets does not list Indirect as a volatile function, however I'm guessing something unexpected or undocumented may be happening here. I also presume you aren't having your spreadsheet recalculate every few minutes.  Can you post your raw custom function as you would with the variables and inputs?

Comment: @pgSystemTester I updated the first post with my function

Comment: Update: I changed the `INDIRECT()` calls to `INDEX()` but that doesn't seems to help. When I look at the logs, the functions still ran randomly, one in 3 hours apart, then 5 hours, 1 hour and then the latest one in 40 minutes

Comment: I'm not sure. Unless your section `// some calculations` is doing something that's not available on the front of any sheet, then you would probably be better off to use a *NAMED function* (a relatively new feature in google sheets). You can then set the inputs as you'd like and output.

Comment: Can you please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet with the script so we can try to replicate your issue.

Comment: Update, I have narrowed down the issue. I started a new spreadsheet, created a custom function that did nothing and called it in a cell like this `=testFunction()`. I leave spreadsheet page aside for an hour and then came back and refreshed the page, the custom function was executed in the log. But refreshing the page did not trigger the function to run again.